# BDD keywords on Mocha

Tags: mocha.js, bdd

What is the meaning of these keyword? I attempted to Google but havn't found anything.
 **describe() context() it() specify()**

[Mocha documentation](https://mochajs.org/#interfaces)

Comment: is your question what those functions do in mocha or is your question about BDD in general?

Comment: Hi Rhayene, my first priority is what those functions do in Mocha, and what are their APIs in detail.